# Rails 3.2.8 not firing ajax callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I'm having problems with rails 3.2.8 and ajax callbacks... it seems those are not firing at all... I've tried binding with Jquery code (I can see the js script on the chrome toolbox) and I've even tried putting the :success => 'alert("bla")' on the link_to line, but it still doesn't do anything... the controller works since my row is actually deleted... but can't bindd to the callbacks! please help!

Here is my view line:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', pet, :method => :delete, :remote=>true, :class => 'delete_pet' %></td>
```

Here is my controller action

```
def destroy
    @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
    @pet.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(pets_url) }
      format.js { render :nothing => true }
    end
  end
```

and here is my js code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.delete_pet').bind("ajax:before", function(){alert('bla2');})
                    .bind("ajax:success", function(){alert('bla2');})
                    .bind("ajax:failure", function(){alert('bla2');})
                    .bind("ajax:complete", function(){alert('bla2');});
});
```

Comment: Make sure that there isn't a conflicting jQUery included in the source. Check the browser console for any output too.

Comment: Genius! That was the problem! on one of my tries.. I included manually the jquery js file on my application.js ... there was no error.. but that seemed to conflict with rails jquery! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that on my application.js I was including manually a jquery file... like this..

```
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom
```

shame on me!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 format.js { render :nothing => true }
```

with

```
 format.json { render :nothing => true }
```

and also replace

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', pet, :method => :delete, :remote=>true, :class => 'delete_pet' %>
```

with

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', pet, :method => :delete, :remote=>true, 'data-type'=>'json', :class => 'delete_pet' %>
```

Comment: i did this but now.. on the chrome toolbox "I get this error GET http://localhost:3000/pets 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Thanks Emrah, but that didn't solve the issue... now it doesn't do anything... no error, just like at the beggining.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar issues with the `respond_to` blocks. I've gotten around it  temporarily by checking the `request`. For example, you're code would look like:

```
def destroy
  @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
  @pet.destroy

  if request.xhr? 
    # the request was received via an AJAX request
    render :nothing => true
  else
    redirect_to(pets_url)
  end
end
```

Not as elegant as the `resond_to` block, but it seems to reliably work as expected.

Good luck!

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.. but something might be wrong on my project.. I mean, not event the ajax:before callback is not firing.. shouldn't that be firing before the ajax call?